# Are operation settings questions to Graphic Design Applications off topic here?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49640/why-is-there-an-over-allocation-of-ram-as-illustrator-loads-a-file) about the system settings / architecture of Graphic Design software, and received a comment that it had nothing to do with Graphic Design. Are questions requesting user experience of Graphic Design software settings and operations really that far off topic here?

Comment: It is always a good idea to quote the question to which you refer, as the link is now dead, and readers can no longer see the original question which you raised the issue about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

How to adjust, change, run, install, uninstall, etc are all off topic. They are **not** design related.

Software tech support is **not** supported here. The manufacturer of the software will **always** be in a better position to address technical issues with their own product.

Succinct, fact-based, definitive answers to technical support questions are often *not* possible because too much information about a *specific* user's computer or environment are contributing factors. We are not designed to be "Adobe's help line" Sorry.

**Regardless of the quality of the manufacturer's services, you will only *really* get an answer from them. If they deny a problem exists, then it's localized and you need to troubleshoot the local system, which we clearly can not do here. Thus off-topic.**

A carpenter asking how to repair his air compressor is not about construction.

A mechanic asking how to fix his lift is not about auto-repair.

A beautician asking how to sharpen scissors is not about hairdressing.

And so on....

Comment: Sure, all that is true. But a carpenter asking what PSI settings another contractor uses on his compressor is related to construction. I felt that my question was more about setting for the software, than about the hardware the software resides on.

Comment: Illustrator has **no** RAM settings. So even that argument falls apart. Sorry Ben, just off-topic.

Comment: That can only be answered when you consider all the hardware involved.

Comment: No problem I appreciate your time. I'll try elsewhere. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is in regards to **hardware** issues and not **design** issues.  We are trying to target design related questions.  Asking software questions like yours on hardware isn't going to get the best answer on GD.SE.  Many people on this site probably couldnt tell you where the RAM is located.  That said you were suggested to contact the software provider but you commented that they deny it exists.

You yourself even said it may not be 100% on topic.  In reality this is what you pay for so all we can suggest is for you to make a help ticket on Adobe or contact their support.  I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I feel that the question is about software settings, but be that as it may I accept that it's off topic. I will move on.

Comment: have a great weekend and good luck

Comment: Thanks, you do the same.